# mysql optimize query for paging

Tags: php, mysql, limit, paging

pls can anybody help me width this query?
I cannot find solution for it.

`SELECT *,p.cat_id, cat_name FROM    (
        SELECT  cat_id
        FROM    categories
        ORDER BY cat_id
        LIMIT 700000, 10
        ) o
JOIN    categories p
ON      p.cat_id = o.cat_id
ORDER BY p.cat_id`

It is very fast on table with 800 000 records, but what I need is to sort data with order by clause and where claue,too - for paging. If I use order by it si very slow or result is not ordered correctly>

```
SELECT *, p.cat_id, cat_name FROM(
    SELECT  cat_id
    FROM    categories
    LIMIT 700000, 10
    ) o JOIN    categories p
ON      p.cat_id = o.cat_id
ORDER BY p.cat_name

page 1
LIMIT 700000,5:
 id      name
 12525525   car
 15155151   carpet
 1521512i   zone

page 2
LIMIT 700005,5
 id        name
12525525   carefull
15155151   excellent
52151222   drive
```

I need result:

```
page 1 car 
carpet
drive 
excellent ... etc.


f.e. , this is very slow ofcourse >
SELECT *, p.cat_id, cat_name 
FROM    (
        SELECT  cat_id
        FROM    categories
        **ORDER BY cat_name**
        LIMIT 700000, 10
        ) o
JOIN    categories p
ON      p.cat_id = o.cat_id
ORDER BY p.cat_name
```

primary key cat_id, autoincrement
I have indexes on fields in table

Many thanks for help or some ideas

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need to `JOIN` the same table, and you have to do the `ORDER BY` in an inner query to be ordered correctly with the `WHWRE` clause in the outer one:

```
 SET @rownum = 0;
 SELECT t.*, t.rank as TableRank
 FROM
 (
    SELECT *,  (@rownum := @rownum + 1) as rank
    FROM categories c 
    ORDER BY c.cat_name
 ) t 
 WHERE rank BETWEEN ((@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1)
 AND (@PageNum * @PageSize)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response , I dont know where iam doing mistake, it doesnt work for me. Iam trying to write query for pagination which will be very fast with 1 000 000 records in table including  where condition and order by sorting  ...which is equal to result .... select * from categories where category_group = 'parts' and category_id = '12452' order by category_name limit 800 000,20. But without limit clause which is slow (f.e.limit 800 000,20) .I dont know how to achieve fast sorting.  I created indexes on database, but its still slow for me. Any help or comment will be helpfull for me